# Calculating distribution and expected values of minimum and maximum of independent uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am having some problems with this exercise, can someone help me?

Let $X_1,X_2$ be independent and identically uniform on $[0,a]$.
Let $U:= \min(X_1,X_2)$ and $V:= \max(X_1,X_2)$.

Calculate the distribution function of $U,V,$ and $E[U],E[V],Cov(U,V)$

So what I have done is:
for $F_V(x)\overset{\text{since iid}}=F_{X_1}^2=x^2/a^2$

$F_u(x)\overset{\text{since iid}}=1-(1-F_{X_1})^2=1-(1-\frac{a}{x})^2$

We have $f_v(x)=d/dx(x^2/a^2)=\frac{2x}{a^2}_{(0\leq x\leq a)}$

and for $f_u(x)=d/dx(1-(1-\frac{a}{x})^2)=-\dfrac{2a\cdot\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)}{x^2}_{(0\leq x\leq a)}$

So we have $E[V]=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{2x^2}{a^2}=\dfrac{2a}{3}$

And $E[U]=\int_0^a x\dfrac{2a\cdot\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)}{x^2}= \infty$

And here starts the problems: I think that how I calculated the two expected values is wrong since I got that E[U] is divergent.

Moreover, if I had calculated the two expected values well, I would not know how to calculate $E[UV]$ to calculate $Cov(U,V)=E[UV]-E[U]E[V]$

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and how should I calculate $E[UV]$?

Comment: How did you arrive at those formulas for calculating the expectations? Recall that $E[X]=\int_0^\infty P(X>x)dx$ for any non-negative random variable $X$. Also, to calculate $E[UV]$, note that $UV=X_1 X_2$.

Comment: @jakobdt From Wikipedia: Now consider a random variable X which has a probability density function given by a function f on the real number line. This means that the probability of X taking on a value in any given open interval is given by the integral of f over that interval. The expectation of X is then given by the integral ${E} [X]=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }xf(x)\,dx \\$

and since we have uniformal distribution I thought that the limits were $0$ and $a$

Comment: Of course, my bad. However, I now see the mistake. In your expression for $F_U$ it should be $x/a$ and not $a/x$.

Comment: O what a stupid error, thanks. The rest should be fine, right? @jakobdt

Comment: Yes, I believe so.